# Tridion Unable to Query Active Directory

Tags: 2013

I am having an issue while adding users to Tridion CM from AD. My AD is having around 8000 users and Tridion says its not able Query AD because the no of users exceeds 1000

Comment: Have you asked SDL support?

Comment: Please share the error message

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to query AD in order to add users. Adding a user via the API just requires that you know the correct AD identity of the person. Here's an example of how to add a user via the core service using Powershell. For the full code, and some more useful examples of similar things, check out [the blog article](http://www.indivirtual.nl/blog/set-rights-permissions-using-sdl-tridion-core-service-api/) I lifted this example from.

```
$testUserDescription = "Test User 1"
$testUserTitle = "TRIDIONDEV\test1"
$testUser = $core.GetDefaultData([ItemType]::User, $null, $null)
$testUser.Title = $testUserTitle
$testUser.Description = $testUserDescription
$testUser = $core.Create($testUser, $defaultReadOptions)
```

Of course, this is just one possibility. The [old Tridion power tools](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/powertools.aspx) had an Add User tool. Maybe someone's already created an up-to-date GUI extension.